# Angular Material - MatTable expandable row animation

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently I have built a `MatTable` with expandable rows:

```
<!-- Hidden cell -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let myModel" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
        <div
            class="detail-cell"
            [@detailExpand]="myModel.isExpanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
        >
            <my-inner-component
                ...
            ></my-inner-component>
        </div>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

And the row:

```
<!-- Hidden row -->
<tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let myModel; columns: ['expandedDetail']"
></tr>
```

The expandable row has an animation attached:

```
animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
        state('collapsed, void', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display: 'none' })),
        state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
        transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ])
]
```

Being that I display a lot of rows, and that `my-inner-component` is a heavy component, I want it to be created only when the row gets expanded.
So i added:

```
*ngIf="myModel.isExpanded"
```

to the containing `div`.

However the animation, obviously, breaks.
How can I solve this problem? I'd like to maintain the animation if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `entry`/`leave` transitions:

Animations in ts file:

```
animations: [
  trigger(
    'detailExpand', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display: 'none' }),
        animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)', style({ height: '*' }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        style({ height: '*' }),
        animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display: 'none' }))
      ])
    ]
  )
]
```

Using it in template:

```
<my-inner-component *ngIf="myModel.isExpanded" [@detailExpand]>
  ...
</my-inner-component>
```

Comment: The closing animation doesn't work. It gets closed immediatly because the `my-inner-component` is no more there

Comment: Btw, seems it works better if I move the `*ngIf` and the `[@detailExpand]` on the `div`. Any idea why? On the inner component it is lagging

Comment: That's interesting but very strange, I'm sorry, I don't know why this is happening...